# How can i add form_select to some fixed drop-down in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using drop down as input in form that drop down list in dependent on user. now i want to add "N/A" drop down to every user. how can i do in my existing code?

```
    <%= form.select :responsibility, options_for_select(@responsibilities.collect{ |responsibility| [responsibility.responsibility_matrix] }), {  prompt: { responsibility: ' ' } } %>
```

Comment: Do you want to add "N/A" option to your list of options or I misunderstood?

Comment: yes N/A to drop-down list for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```rb
 <%= form.select :responsibility, options_for_select(@responsibilities.collect{ |responsibility| [responsibility.responsibility_matrix] }.unshift(['N/A', 'N/A'])), {  prompt: { responsibility: ' ' } } %>
```